# How to own console for time of program execution?

Tags: c#, winapi, user-interface, console

I'm trying to write a program, that works in console or GUI mode, depending on execution parameters. I've managed to write following sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace wfSketchbook
{
    static class Program
    {
        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool AttachConsole(int processId);

        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool AllocConsole();

        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool FreeConsole();

        private const int ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS = -1;

        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                if (!AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS))
                    AllocConsole();
                Console.WriteLine("Welcome to console!");
                Console.ReadKey();
                FreeConsole();
            }
            else
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It generally works, however when program is called from the system command-line, the cmd seems not to be aware, that program works in console mode and exits immediately:

```
d:\Dokumenty\Dev\C#\Projekty\Win32\Sketchbook\wfSketchbook\bin\Debug>wfSketchbook.exe test

d:\Dokumenty\Dev\C#\Projekty\Win32\Sketchbook\wfSketchbook\bin\Debug>Welcome to console!

d:\Dokumenty\Dev\C#\Projekty\Win32\Sketchbook\wfSketchbook\bin\Debug>
```

I'd rather expect following output:

```
d:\Dokumenty\Dev\C#\Projekty\Win32\Sketchbook\wfSketchbook\bin\Debug>wfSketchbook.exe test

Welcome to console!

d:\Dokumenty\Dev\C#\Projekty\Win32\Sketchbook\wfSketchbook\bin\Debug>
```

How may I correct this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any reliable way to make a Windows application a console and a GUI.  Your program is a Windows application - so Windows launches you outside of the console window - when your program starts you aren't attached to the console window.

You could change your project output to a Console application in the project's properties.  But then you would always get a console window.  Windows could see that your application was marked as a console application and create a console even before you ran.

See this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/01/01/9259142.aspx) for more information and links to some work arounds.

Answer (score 3):

There is no ideal solution for this.  Cmd.exe is only going to automatically wait for the program to complete if it can see that the .exe is a console mode app.  Which won't be the case for your app.  One workaround is to tell it to wait:

> start /wait yourapp.exe [arguments]

The other is to always use AllocConsole().  Which the side-effect that it creates a second console window.  Changing the application type to Console then calling FreeConsole() is not ideal either, the flash of the window is quite noticeable.  Pick your poison.