# How to create a Windows Forms program that can also run at the command prompt

Tags: c#, winforms, command-line-arguments

I've created a program that has two projects: a windows UI and an "engine". I would like to make it so that the user can execute the program from a command prompt passing in some arguments and the engine will automatically execute them and spit out the results. OR the user can launch the UI and choose all of their options via dropdown lists and such and then click a button to tell the engine to do it's work.
I actually already have it working using something I found a long time ago, but I'm trying to see if there's an easier way. The way I found involves adding a Win32 class and creating externals to AllocConsole, FreeConsole, and AttachConsole from kernel32.dll.
Is there an easier way? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to own console for time of program execution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058491/how-to-own-console-for-time-of-program-execution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's simple, make your windows forms application and in the `Main` method check the command line parameters and in case your parameters are there, instead of calling

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

simply call your engine and start processing.

it's important to code your engine properly and have also the UI using the same engine when the user is starting those commands from the user interface, so to avoid any useless code duplication.

we use this approach in many programs and we are satisfied, if you do not call `Application.Run(...)` your program will simply terminate when the `Main` method ends.

Comment: It's not that simple - either the application is marked as a GUI app and no console is created, so you need to use `AllocConsole` etc.  or you mark it as a console app and it will always create a console window.  It's the console portion of this that's the problem, not just not showing a UI.

Comment: shf301, the issue you bring up may be what I ran into some time ago when I made this, but, Davide, it sounds like this method is working for you, right? Do you mark the app as a GUI app or a console app?

Answer (score 1):

It's even simpler. Create a Console application. It will parse the command line to get the parameters, then will call your engine.

Let the WinForms application worry about GUI, let the Console application worry about the command-line.

Answer (score 1):

Create four separate configurations, two for GUI and two for Console:

[image: DebugConsole, DebugGui, ReleaseConsole, ReleaseGui]

The above screenshot is for *solution configurations.* You’ll have to do the same again for the *project* (in the above screenshot the project that has those four configurations is Rummage). Here is an excerpt from `Rummage.csproj`:

```
[...]
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'DebugGui|AnyCPU' ">
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'ReleaseGui|AnyCPU' ">
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'DebugConsole|AnyCPU'">
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;CONSOLE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'ReleaseConsole|AnyCPU'">
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;CONSOLE</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
  </PropertyGroup>
[...]
```

Notice especially:

- The Console configurations have `<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>` (that makes them a console app) while the Release configurations have `<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>`.
- Both Console configurations have the `CONSOLE` constant defined. That way you can use `#if CONSOLE [...] #else [...] #endif` to have console-/GUI-specific code. For example, the Main method might look like this:

  ```
  [STAThread]
  static int Main(string[] args)
  {
      #if CONSOLE
          return MainConsole(args);
      #else
          return MainGui(args);
      #endif
  }
  ```

  ... and then you can have the WinForms stuff in `MainGui` and the command-line parsing stuff in `MainConsole`.

This way you can run (and debug) either the GUI or the console version in Visual Studio, while in a build script you can simply build all of them (and into different directories or different EXE file names).